# How to initialize struct with its zero values if referenced struct has nil pointers

Tags: go

I don't know if there following if possible.
I have:

```
type A struct {
  Val int
}
```

and

```
type B struct {
  Val *int
}
```

Then I have this working snippet:

```
func main() {
  b := B{Val: new(int)}
  *b.Val = 1

  a := A{Val: *b.Val}
}
```

What I want to achieve is that the variable `a` gets initialized with its zero values, hence its `Val` being `0` in case `*b.Val = nil` without having to check with an `if` condition. This is a very simplified version and the reason I am trying to do this is that my `B` struct has many properties that might or might not be filled by different entities. Such properties make more sense as `nil` in case they are not filled and I am trying to avoid checking with an `if` condition for each one of them if they are `nil` before assigning their non-nil value or the zero value to the properties of `A`

Comment: You don't ned to initialize anything as the zero value, the default value is the zero value. If you want to conditionally assign a value to the zero value, then you need a conditional statement.

Comment: @JimB The second case you mentioned. Is there a way to do it inline by any chance? Cause I know when initializing a struct you cannot place conditional statements in between the {} of the initialization

Comment: No, you cannot have conditional statements within a [composite literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals). You could however make some sort of helper functions to return whatever value you want. Constructors are often used where something more complicated than the zero value is required.

Comment: @Tarta You could define a helper function and use _that_ in the composite literal. But Go is conservative with inline expressions / syntactic sugar. (eg: `A{Val: helper(b.Val)}`

Answer (score 0):

golang automatically creates variable with default value whenever you initialize them so there is no need to do anything. you can simply use either of the syntax mentioneb below:

```
a := new(A)
a := A{}
var a A
```

all above syntax will intialize its variable with zero